# Embedding a NoSQL DB into an MVC web application

Tags: model-view-controller, nosql

I'm working on a development plan for an MVC web application.  I'm trying to see what my options are as far as a MVC application with and embedded noSQL document-oriented database is concerned.  I'm looking at ASP.Net MVC with an embedded RavenDB instance, but I wanted to see what my other options are.  RavenDB would be perfect if not for the commercial licensing fees, this is a commercial project I'm building for my employer, so unfortunately I cannot use the free version of RavenDB.  Is there a similar alternative combination?  It doesn't have to be the .Net MVC framework, my requirements are an MVC framework with an embedded noSQL database to be used as the model.  Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked Cassandra, MongoDB, CouchDB?

Comment: I've looked at MongoDB and CouchDB, but couldn't find any resources that described how to integrate either one into an MVC web application in the same way RavenDB can be integrated into an ASP.Net MVC project.  I wouldn't mind using MongoDB if I knew of a way to embed it into an MVC application like RavenDB.

Comment: MVC is a web tier, MongoDB is a database. They aren't supposed to be dependent on one another. The only thing that might be relevant is the existence of a .Net client for "speaking" with the database.

Comment: My apologies, I said integrate when I meant embed.  I want to be able to embed different document-oriented databases the same way RavenDB can be embedded into an MVC App.  Thanks.

Comment: My answer is same as before :-) But see for example http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2010/04/16/nosql-with-mongodb-norm-and-asp-net-mvc.aspx